# what to do when windows vps stucks on "please wait" screen

Tags: remote-desktop, windows-server-2012, vps

I recently bought a VPS Server with Windows Server 2012R2, I Connected to it several times without problem via RDP, but now when I'm trying to connect, it remains in "Please wait" screen and never logs in. I don't have direct access to the server to restart it by hand, what should I do? to be able to connect and solve the problem.

Comment: The first thing to check is on the client side, and a possible firewall rule that would prevent you from connecting. You usually don't have to wait that long to get a "yes" or "no" answer from a remote server. Go to your Firewall advanced properties, on the Outgoing traffic side, and check if both Remote Desktop Protocol and its Websocket counterpart are allowed to communicate with the outside world.

Comment: I'm using ubuntu on my side (client) and my firewall is inactive.

Comment: Are you sure the VPS provider doesn't have a control panel with _at least_ a "power off" / "reboot" button? That seems like the absolute bare minimum that a VPS provider should have...

Comment: Not if it's barebone. Could be that some maintenance is taking place at the other end. You could delete all preferences in your client, and start with a fresh set of connection parameters. Clear cache, reboot your PC. Could also be that the NAT at the other end is being reset, in which case the public IP you're connecting to has changed. Do you have another ID to connect through, like a Web link or a server name?

Comment: @Didier If It's a NAT reset shouldn't it drop my connection and reject me? I did all you said, nothing new. not another ID to connect through but I have another account other than administrator, and it's the same.

Comment: Interesting! now I ping my server and there is no response!!!

Comment: It's probably a maintenance issue. Your server or the rack it's in must be undergoing a maintenance cycle, and you're locked out for the moment. It's inconvenient, but it happens. I don't know who hosts your server, but I know that companies such as OVH have been under DDoS attack lately, and they're trying to beef up their security.

Comment: @Didier don't understand something. If it's offline why when I use rdp to connect it asks me for password, and then goes to that "please wait" screen, if it's really offline, it shouldn't respond anyway.

Comment: RDP doesn't work that way. There's a client (on your PC), an Internet connection and a server at the other end. On your end, PC-side, the RDP client will do whatever it is it's set do do: open a connection window to the last server and username you connected to, ask for a password (or not, if you have saved your credentials), and try to establish a TCP/IP connection to the remote server. On your end, everything seems fine, unless your client needs an update that you haven't installed yet. There seems to be an issue, either on the network between your PC and the server, or on the server itself.

Comment: So, if you can browse the Web just fine, but can't connect to your target remote server, there's a good chance that the problem lies there. Have you contacted the company that hosts your server and ask if they're encountering some downtime at the moment? If the problem persists for more than a few hours, it could be something more serious, like a security breach or a global denial-of-service.

Answer (score 1):

I have found the temporary solution.
You may reboot remote host without RDP-login to it from other windows machine in domain.
192.168.111.11 is the remote IP address:

```
shutdown.exe /r /f /m \\192.168.111.11 /t 0
```

/r - reboot
/f - force processes to close
/m \\host - remote action on other host
/t 00 - wait 0 sec

Answer (score 0):

You may try asking your network administrator to troubleshoot it or file a complaint about this issue to the  authority because without having a physical access to device it will not be easy to troubleshoot it,else you wait for some time .

Answer (score 0):

The following has worked for me on Windows 11 using and administrator account. I have not touched the machine's configuration. You might need to change some settings for it to work. I might have gotten lucky...

From Linux you can install Samba and do:

```
net rpc shutdown -r -I <ip address> -U <username>%<password>
```

The `-r` option should make it reboot, else it would shutdown.
Leaving out `%<password>` makes the terminal prompt you to enter one.